# How to combine different mono and use the combined result with error handling?

Tags: project-reactor

I have a scenario where i need to use different mono which could return me errors and set map values to null if error is returned.
Ex:

```
Mono<A> a=Some api call;
Mono<A> b=Some api giving error;
Mono<A> c=Some api call;
```

Now i want to set the resulting response to map

```
Map<String,A> m=new HashMap<>();
m.put("a",a);
m.put("b",null);
m.put("c",c);
```

Can anyone help on how to do all this in reactive non blocking way.
I tried zip but it will not execute if any of the api return error or if i use onErrorReturn(null).

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

To solve your problems, you will have to use some tricks. The problem is that :

- Giving an empty mono or mono that ends in error cancel zip operation ([source: Mono#zip javadoc](https://projectreactor.io/docs/core/release/api/reactor/core/publisher/Mono.html#zip-reactor.core.publisher.Mono-reactor.core.publisher.Mono-))
- Reactive streams do not allow null values ([source: Reactive stream spec, table 2: Subscribers, bullet 13](https://github.com/reactive-streams/reactive-streams-jvm#user-content-2.13))

Also, note that putting a null value in a hash map is the same as cancelling any previous value associated with the key (it's important in case you're updating an existing map).

Now, to bypass your problem, you can add an abstraction layer, and wrap your values in domain objects.
You can have an object that represents a query, another a valid result, and the last one will mirror an error.
With that, you can design publishers that will always succeed with non null values.
That's a technic used a lot in functional programming : common errors are part of the (one possible) result value.

Now, let's see the example that create a new Map from multiple Monos:

```java
import reactor.core.publisher.Flux;
import reactor.core.publisher.Mono;

import java.time.Duration;
import java.util.Map;

public class BypassMonoError {

    /**
     * An object identified by a key. It serves to track which key to associate to computed values
     * @param <K> Type of the key
     */
    static class Identified<K> {

        protected final K id;

        Identified(K id) {
            this.id = id;
        }

        public K getId() {
            return id;
        }
    }

    /**
     * Describe the result value of an operation, along with the key associated to it.
     *
     * @param <K> Type of the identifier of the result
     * @param <V> Value type
     */
    static abstract class Result<K, V> extends Identified<K> {
        Result(K id) {
            super(id);
        }

        /**
         *
         * @return Computed value on success, or null if the operation has failed. Note that here, we cannot tell from
         * a success returning a null value or an error
         */
        abstract V getOrNull();
    }

    static final class Success<K, V> extends Result<K, V> {

        private final V value;

        Success(K id, V value) {
            super(id);
            this.value = value;
        }

        @Override
        V getOrNull() {
            return value;
        }
    }

    static final class Error<K, V> extends Result<K, V> {

        private final Exception error;

        Error(K id, Exception error) {
            super(id);
            this.error = error;
        }

        @Override
        V getOrNull() {
            return null;
        }

        public Exception getError() {
            return error;
        }
    }

    /**
     * A request that can asynchronously generate a result for the associated identifier.
     */
    static class Query<K, V> extends Identified<K> {
        private final Mono<V> worker;

        Query(K id, Mono<V> worker) {
            super(id);
            this.worker = worker;
        }

        /**
         * @return The operator that computes the result value. Note that any error is silently wrapped in an
         * {@link Error empty result with error metadata}.
         */
        public Mono<Result<K, V>> runCatching() {
            return worker.<Result<K, V>>map(success -> new Success<>(id, success))
                    .onErrorResume(Exception.class, error -> Mono.just(new Error<K, V>(id, error)));
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        final Flux<Query<String, String>> queries = Flux.just(
                new Query("a", Mono.just("A")),
                new Query("b", Mono.error(new Exception("B"))),
                new Query("c", Mono.delay(Duration.ofSeconds(1)).map(v -> "C"))
        );

        final Flux<Result<String, String>> results = queries.flatMap(query -> query.runCatching());
        final Map<String, String> myMap = results.collectMap(Result::getId, Result::getOrNull)
                .block();

        for (Map.Entry<String, String> entry : myMap.entrySet()) {
            System.out.printf("%s -> %s%n", entry.getKey(), entry.getValue());
        }
    }
}
```

*Note* : In the above example, we silently ignore any occurred error. However, when using the flux, you can test if a result is an error, and if it is, you are free to design your own error management (log, fail-first, send in another flux, etc.).

This outputs:

```
a -> A
b -> null
c -> C
```